# Spring - OpenJPAThe context has been closed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have been struggling with error and read quite a many posts on SO but none of the solution 
worked.
I want to query database and get a list of record from the tables.

Here's the method that's doing this-

```
public <T> List<T> retrieveByNamedQuery(final String queryName) throws EpPersistenceException {
    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOG.debug(LOG_NAMED_QUERY + queryName);
    }
    try {
        return entityManager.createNamedQuery(queryName).getResultList();
    } catch (final DataAccessException e) {
        throw new EpPersistenceException(CAUGHT_AN_EXCEPTION, e);
    }
}
```

Here's how my xml where I have defined my named query looks like:

```
<entity class="ProductAssociationImpl">

    <named-native-query name="GET_PLAN_PARENT_DEVICE_UIDPK">
        <query>SELECT PA.* FROM TPRODUCTASSOCIATION PA, TPRODUCT P WHERE pa.TARGET_PRODUCT_UID = 100163 AND PA.SOURCE_PRODUCT_UID = P.UIDPK AND P.END_DATE IS NULL AND P.PRODUCT_TYPE_UID = 1</query>
    </named-native-query>
</entity>
```

Here's the beans definition in the xml

```
<beans>
<!--  Entity Manager Factory -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="com.elasticpath.persistence.impl.LocalApplicationEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="commerce-persistence-unit"/>
  <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence-renamed.xml"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sharedEntityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory">
        <ref bean="entityManagerFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="com.elasticpath.persistence.impl.JpaSessionFactoryImpl">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceEngineTarget"
    class="com.elasticpath.persistence.impl.JpaPersistenceEngineImpl">
    <property name="entityManager" ref="sharedEntityManager"/>
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceEngine"
    class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces">
        <value>com.elasticpath.persistence.PersistenceEngine</value>
    </property>
    <property name="target">
        <ref local="persistenceEngineTarget" />
    </property>
</bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory">
    <ref bean="entityManagerFactory"/>
  </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

When I run my code I get this exception:

```
    <openjpa-1.0.1-rexported fatal user error> org.apache.renamed.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: The context has been closed.  The stack trace at which the context was closed is held in the embedded exception.
    FailedObject: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.renamed.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.assertOpen(BrokerImpl.java:4302)
    at org.apache.renamed.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beginOperation(BrokerImpl.java:1710)
    at org.apache.renamed.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:783)
    at org.apache.renamed.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:769)
    at org.apache.renamed.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:765)
    at org.apache.renamed.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:517)
    at org.apache.renamed.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.renamed.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:277)
    at com.elasticpath.persistence.impl.JpaPersistenceEngineImpl.retrieveByNamedQuery(JpaPersistenceEngineImpl.java:460)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
    at $Proxy58.retrieveByNamedQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.acn.sfweb.controller.impl.ACNAddToCartControllerImpl.handleRequestInternal(ACNAddToCartControllerImpl.java:300)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.elasticpath.commons.filter.impl.CachingControlFilter.doFilter(CachingControlFilter.java:168)
    at com.elasticpath.sfweb.filters.EpFilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(EpFilterToBeanProxy.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.elasticpath.sfweb.filters.CustomerSessionFilter.doFilter(CustomerSessionFilter.java:76)
    at com.elasticpath.sfweb.filters.EpFilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(EpFilterToBeanProxy.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at com.elasticpath.commons.filter.impl.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:49)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at com.elasticpath.commons.filter.impl.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:49)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.securechannel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:138)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.elasticpath.commons.filter.impl.EncodingFilter.handleFilter(EncodingFilter.java:138)
    at com.elasticpath.commons.filter.impl.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:580)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

On many of the SO posts and other blogs people mentioned that tx-manager might be missing in the application xml, but I can see that it is already present there ( See above).
Here's the snippet that I have in my beans definintion

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory">
    <ref bean="entityManagerFactory"/>
  </property>
</bean>
```

P.S. - This is an old piece of code that I cannot upgrade and is using Spring 2.0 Xml and not annotations

What am I missing?